# What is a simple algorithm / approach to store key-value (number-number) pairs *in disk* for quick access by key?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, store

I need to store many Long-Long pairs **in disk, not in memory**, for example:

```
(123, 2)
(1253, 3)
(12345, 6)
...
```

So later I can easily do:

```
long value = get(123); // => 2
```

Is there a simple approach to do that? I am hoping it does not need to be as complicated as a hashtable in disk.

To make it clear, the pairs will NOT be stored in memory, they will be written straight to a file or set of files in disk.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple key/value stores available. A quite comprehensive list can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key-value_stores).

One good alternative is to use [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) which is a fast and easy-to-use NoSQL database which supports disk storage and transactions.

To use it, simply follow the instructions in the [cheat sheet](http://www.mapdb.org/doc/cheatsheet.pdf):

```
File file = new File(“dbFileName”);
DB db = DBMaker.newFileDB(file).make();

//use map
Map map = db.getHashMap(“mapName”);
map.put(“aa”,”bb”);

//commit and close database
db.commit();
db.close();
```

Plus, it obviously works for `Long` values as well!

Comment: Sorry but your eyes skipped the part where I said IN DISK.

Comment: Ok, but what do you men by IN DISK?

Comment: It won't be stored in memory, it will be stored in disk (in a file or set of files).

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to do it myself. Nothing against MapDB, but I would like to find a smart/simple way, if one exists, to do that myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a hashtable (best way to store key/value pairs), you just have to serialize it.

You can access your serialized files and read those in. For example, after reserialization (assuming hashmap style): `Long x = Long.parseLong(y.get("123"));`

Comment: No. The values will NEVER go be in MEMORY. They will always be in disk.

Comment: How can something never go in memory? The program itself uses memory.
Do you mean that you ALREADY HAVE a file, and it's stored like (123, 2) etc, and you want to get it later?

Comment: Dude, I have to store a lot of data and I don't want to use memory, I want to store this data in a file or set of files and then read them somehow. In real-time! Got it?

Comment: You can't avoid using memory, anything that passes through the program immediately "uses" memory. 

Are you against reading in parts of the data into a map, serialize, refresh the map, reading the next part, serialize, and repeating?

Even in realtime this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I give up StackOverflow!

Comment: The person asking the question is clearly asking for something efficient, and when she says "no memory" she means no long term storage, not literally that not a single byte of memory will be used.

Comment: @JasonN if you look at the discussion under her question, that is exactly method my solution uses. A temporary memory storage, using serialization for logn term storage instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a CS homework, I would simply use a Redis persistent instance.

http://www.redis.io

Comment: Nothing against redis, but I would like to find a smart/simple way, if one exists, to do that myself.